# Github commit and import project from a folder in a repository

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I've a repository. Inside it, there will be multiple folders which will contain different projects. Now I want to commit my project only to that folder and pull only from it. I'm using Android Studio for this. Currently, I'm using different branches to do the job. Can this be done directly from Android studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 way

**1 Using submodule**

[github submodule](https://gist.github.com/gitaarik/8735255)

repository 1 (your project)

- folder 1
- folder 2
- submodule folder

**2 Just ignore it**

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Btw: i suggest using `git command` for more understanding about git

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm glad to hear that

Comment: I have two repo now - 1 main repo and another sub repo which I linked to the main repo. I made a change in the sub repo which is not reflected in the main repo even when I use **git submodule update**. Am I doing anything wrong in this?

Comment: what do you mean `linked to main repo`? Please paste the command here

Comment: My main repo is mypackse. The sub-repo is Itinerary. The steps are:
1. **git submodule add git@github.com:Itinerary.git mypackse/subfolder.**
This worked fine.
2. Then I made some changes in Itinerary and pushed in the Itinerary repo. This worked fine but are not reflected in mypackse.
3. Now I used **git submodule update** which should reflect those Itinerary changes in the mypackse repo but it is not happening. Have I done something wrong? Please help

Comment: In main repo: 1. `git submodule add` then `git submodule update` will work?

Comment: Step 1 and 2 has worked for me. Somehow I can't update my mypackse repo to pull the Itinerary changes. It is still showing the initial commit.

Comment: git submodule will control submodule as a file. So when you update submodule repo. In main project just see submodule repo's hash code change. You can't see what changed in main repo